# Creating an MPAndroidChart to display data, however, nothing is being displayed

Tags: android, firebase, graph, accelerometer, mpandroidchart

This is my source code below trying to display data from my Firebase. My three arrays containing accelerometer data of x, y, and z are printing out as well as my result array.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LineChart chart;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        ArrayList<Double> xValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> zValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();

        setTitle("RealtimeLineChartActivity");

        chart = findViewById(R.id.petChart);
//        chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        // enable description text
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(true);

        // enable touch gestures
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

        // enable scaling and dragging
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
        chart.setPinchZoom(true);

        // set an alternative background color
        chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        LineData data = new LineData();
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        // add empty data
        chart.setData(data);


        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + userID);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot acxSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcX");
                DataSnapshot acySnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcY");
                DataSnapshot aczSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcZ");

                long convert = 1000L;
                int counter = 0;


                System.out.println("Accelerometer X:");
                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acxSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    xValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class)/convert));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < xValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(xValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Accelerometer Y:");

                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acySnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    yValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class))/convert);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < yValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(yValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Accelerometer Z:");

                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : aczSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    zValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class))/convert);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < zValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(zValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Result:");
                for (int i = 0; i < yValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    double sqrtResult = Math.sqrt((xValues.get(i)*xValues.get(i)) + ((yValues.get(i)*yValues.get(i))) + ((zValues.get(i)*zValues.get(i))));
                    result.add(new Entry(counter,(float)sqrtResult));
//                    System.out.println(result.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println(counter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(result, "data set 1");
        set1.setFillAlpha(110);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        LineData data2 = new LineData(dataSets);

        chart.setData(data2);

    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot below of what my emulator looks like when I try to go to the chart screen. Thank you so much in advance!
[Screenshot of a blank chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hAOl.png)

Updated Code Below:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LineChart chart;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        ArrayList<Double> xValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> zValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();

        chart = findViewById(R.id.petChart);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + userID);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot acxSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcX");
                DataSnapshot acySnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcY");
                DataSnapshot aczSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("AcZ");

                long convert = 1000L;
                float counter = 0;


                System.out.println("Accelerometer X:");
                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acxSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    xValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class)/convert));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < xValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(xValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Accelerometer Y:");

                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acySnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    yValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class))/convert);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < yValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(yValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Accelerometer Z:");

                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : aczSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    zValues.add((valueSnapshot.getValue(Double.class))/convert);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < zValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(zValues.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("Result:");
                for (int i = 0; i < yValues.size(); i++)
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    double sqrtResult = Math.sqrt((xValues.get(i)*xValues.get(i)) + ((yValues.get(i)*yValues.get(i))) + ((zValues.get(i)*zValues.get(i))));
                    result.add(new Entry(counter,(float)sqrtResult));
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(result, "data set 1");

//        if (set1 == null)
//        {
//            System.out.println("dataset is empty");
//        }

        set1.setFillAlpha(110);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        LineData data2 = new LineData(dataSets);

        chart.setData(data2);
        chart.invalidate();

    }

}
```

[Still a blank screen after calling chart.invalidate()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PXVh.png)

Comment: add stacktrace after calling chart.notifyDataSetChanged() to this post :)

Answer (score 0):

You are settings data sets to before Firebase triggers DataChange listeners so that, data sets are empty when its set to chart. After entries are added make sure to call `chart.notifyDataSetsChanged()` or `chart.invalidate()`

Comment: Thank you! Would I call chart.invalidate() aftter my for loop of adding the entries to the result arraylist?

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately it crashes my app. :(

Comment: Can you add stacktrace to post?

Comment: How do you add stracktrace? I apologize since I'm new to creating a mobile app! Again, thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Edit your post and add a part UPDATED: after chart.notifyDataSetChanged(). no problem by the way. this is the why this platform exists

Comment: Updated my original post with the code! :) My code would not accept chart.notifyDataSetChanged() as I believe that is what chart.setData() already incorporates, so chart.invalidate() was accepted, however, it would not populate a graph as seen in my second picture.